# How to combine multiple queries of dasl in vsto c# ? Following Queries

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

```cs
string filterSpecificSubject = "@SQL=\"urn:schemas:httpmail:subject\" like '%" + subjectName + "%'";
string filterSpecificSubject = "@SQL=\"urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription\" like '%" + body+ "%'";
string filterSpecificSubject = "@SQL=\"urn:schemas:httpmail:recipient\" like '%" + mailaddress+ "%'";
```

Kindly tell me how to combine them with an "AND" operator?

Answer (score 0):

```
string CombinedQuery = string.Format("({0}) AND ({1}) AND ({2})", query1, query2, query3);
```

Comment: Using the original strings from the question, you would end up with `@SQL=`, three times...

Comment: There is no query1 variable in the original post. That was an example of 3 separate queries

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
string.Format("@SQL=(\"urn:schemas:httpmail:subject\" like '%{0}%') AND (\"urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription\" like '%{1}%') AND (\"urn:schemas:httpmail:recipient\" like '%{2}%')", 
subjectName , body, mailaddress);
```